# What is the "pole-Q frequency"?

Tags: filter, noise, emc, passive-filter, emi-filtering

The following statement is an excerpt from the book *EMI filter design*:

"if the filter is not optimized for characteristic impedance the filter will be prone to peaking at the points of impedance mismatch. If the EMI  filter design is left unchecked, this phenomenon may lead to corresponding elevations in noise amplitude around the ***pole-Q frequency***, causing EMC test failure"

What is the "pole-Q frequency"?

[image]

[image]
<sup>From *EMI filter design* by Richard Lee Ozenbaugh, 3rd edition, page 1-4</sup>

Comment: As far as I know there is no such thing as *pole-Q frequency*. There is Q-factor and, there is pole frequency of course. More details needed; maybe use your camera and post a screen shot.

Comment: @Andy aka, yes this is exactly what I'm confused about. I've attached the whole paragraph to the question.

Comment: Look for other occasions in the book where that term is used to see if they make more sense.

Comment: @WeTech If it's only that occurence then it's possible the author had a temporary crossed neuron (pole frequency with Q factor). It can be confusing but you can ignore that one blooper.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen this is used frequently in literature. I've attached another excerpt from this chapter. does it mean the pole frequency with desired Q factor?

Comment: @Andyaka  I've attached another excerpt from this chapter.

Comment: @WeTech I don't know what the author was thinking but, personally, I haven't met this description-- it's either pole frequency, or Q (quality) factor [of the pole]. When you say "*this is used frequently in literature*", do you mean in this book, or in general, in literature? Because, if the latter, I haven't seen it.

Comment: I cannot confirm that this term is used "frequently" - for me it is the first time within the last 40 years that I have seen this term here in the forum. A pole is characterized by its position in the s-plane - and this is described by the pole frequency wp (length of the pointer between pole and origin) and the angle (expressed as Qp)

Comment: I add myself to the list of people who have never heard of that term. In common TLC electronics literature it's either *Q factor* (of a filter or other kind frequency-selective device, such as a resonator)  or *pole frequency*. Try to check if that author has defined that specific term somewhere near the beginning of the book or in the glossary. Sometimes authors make up terms for something that deem important to talk about for the sake of avoiding repetitions.

Comment: BTW a google search for *"pole-Q frequency"* gives only 9 results! Which is a strong hint that it is NOT a common term in *any* literature.

Comment: Just a suggestion: search in the book the simplest example where the author calculates the pole-Q frequency and compare that result/formulas to whatever online resources provide for that kind of filter. You could infer the meaning of that term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @LvW comment pointed out, It seems that "pole-Q frequency" is well based on this picture.
It's only ... just a "shortcut"...

Same book, page 18.7, nothing strange.
This picture gives effectively ... poles position, Q or zeta=1/(2*Q), and wd or wn.

Based on a single r-L/C filter. (wn=1/sqrt(L*C) ...)

[image]